# How to get child dynamically with name in power shell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

wanted to traverse in json body and get values from list using powershell.

json file

```
{   
 "TopicPropProfiles": [    
    {        
    "TP1":{            
        "enable-duplicate-detection": true,            
        "enable-batched-operations": true,            
        "enable-ordering": true      
        },        
    "TP2":{            
        "max-delivery-count": 3,            
        "enable-batched-operations": true      
        }    
    }    
],    
 "SubPropProfiles": [    
    {        
    "SP1":{            
        "enable-duplicate-detection": true,                        
        "max-size": 1024        
        },        
    "SP2":{            
        "max-delivery-count": 3,            
        "enable-batched-operations": true,                       
        "enable-session": false                  
        }    
    }    
],    
  "Topics":[    
        {        
            "TopicName": "topic1",        
            "SubNames": ["sub1","sub2","sub3"],        
            "TopicPropertyProfile": "TP1",        
            "SubPropertyProfile": "SP2" 
        },    
        {        
            "TopicName": "topic2",        
            "SubNames": ["sub4","sub5","sub6"],        
            "TopicPropertyProfile": "TP2",        
            "SubPropertyProfile": "SP1"    
        }
    ]
}
```

powershell --getting file from somepath($profilepath)

```
$profilejson =  Get-Content -Raw $profilePath | ConvertFrom-Json;
$profileObject = [PSCustomObject]$profilejson;

$TopicProps=$profileObject.TopicPropProfiles.**TP1**;
Write-Host $TopicProps.'enable-duplicate-detection'
```

Wanted to get fields values under TP1 or TP2(this value will be passed dynamically through some other parameters). Is above syntax/approach correct?

Comment: What is your expected answer? Do you want to get "TopicName", "SubNames",        
 "TopicPropertyProfile", "SubPropertyProfile" as output?

Comment: Just `$profilejson.TopicPropProfiles.TP1` but note that `$profilejson.TopicPropProfiles` is an array and this uses [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration), meaning if you want to write to it, you will need to be specific:  `$profilejson.TopicPropProfiles[0].TP1`. As an aside: `[PSCustomObject]$profilejson` is not required and you should lose the tailing semicolon (`;`) -it is not C#.

Comment: I'll take care of semi-colon part , what if TP1 if also in some var like $profile=TP1 then path will be - $profilejson.TopicPropProfiles[0].$profile ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and I got expected results as below:

```
$result = Get-Content "Path" -raw | ConvertFrom-Json 
$result.TopicPropProfiles.TP1
```

[image]

> what if TP1 if also in some var like $profile=TP1 then?

```
$result = Get-Content "path" -raw | ConvertFrom-Json 


$profile='TP1'
$result.TopicPropProfiles[0].$profile
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of specific keys, you can use the dot notation. Example :

```
$json = Get-Content -Raw .\json.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.TopicPropProfiles
```

To see the content of TP1

```
$json.TopicPropProfiles.TP1
```

To get get the value of your first key/value pair inside TP1

```
$json.TopicPropProfiles.TP1.'enable-batched-operations'
```

Like this, you'll get the object returned. If you want the values, you need to use Select-Object

```
$json.TopicPropProfiles.TP1 |Select-Object -ExpandProperty TP1
```